# Deployment of a react app stopped working on GitHub pages

Tags: reactjs, deployment, github-pages

I am doing a React app which I deploy on GitHub pages. https://asaroz.github.io/DCI_Hackathon_TeamE

Deployments worked without much problems before, but now the console gives me this:
[image: github-pages error]

the path to the file seems to be correct:
[image: Path in github]

I deploy with the npm module from GitHub pages.

```
    {
  "homepage": "http://asaroz.github.io/DCI_Hackathon_TeamE/",
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "node-sass": "^6.0.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-simple-image-slider": "^2.3.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

I sadly have no clue what the exact problem is. Perhaps the Response gives me a hint, but I just don't know that much about Response errors jet. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok github pages didn't update/deploy my changes. I don't know why. I fixed the issue by editing a useless space into the file in question on github.

Comment: *"github pages didn't update/deploy my changes"* are the deployment script or snippet in the project's **gitignore**?